# IStartup Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

We have been using IStartup (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`) interface in our hosting infrastructure project for hosting the apps which expose the Configure and ConfigureServices methods, we built that infrastructure around .net core 2.X and since .net core 3.X the default Startup class that comes with the .net core project has changed the return type of ConfigureServices method, previously it used to return an IServiceProvider:

```
IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services);
```

and now it looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

returning nothing back.

I am wondering why is that change not reflected in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` namespace to support the new ConfigureService method signature.
Is there any other namespace I could use?

Comment: Please don't tag `[.net]` Framework if your question is about `[.net-core]` - it's misleading.

Comment: @Llama https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting

Comment: https://github.com/coherentsolutionsinc/aspnetcore-service-fabric-hosting/issues/97

Comment: You're right, it seems. I've deleted my comments. Oddly, the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.istartup.configureservices?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IStartup_ConfigureServices_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_) still shows `IStartup`'s `ConfigureServices` method as returning `IServiceProvider`. Though, `IStartup` used in conjunction with `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` yields a message stating _"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IStartup isn't supported"_ in .NET 5. Not sure about .NET 3.1 though.

Comment: I expect you'll probably have to move over to the `ConfigureContainer` method moving forwards. You could perhaps create your own interface for it in order to enforce its existence, if needs be.

Comment: You could implement your own `IServiceProviderFactory` so that you can pass the `IServiceCollection` into `ConfigureContainer`, and then you can pass the built `IServiceProvider` back. That would allow you to keep a very similar flow to your current one, at least.