# How to return IServiceProvider from Startup.ConfigureServices in .NET Core 7

Tags: c#, startup, asp.net-core-7.0

I have a .NET Core 7 web Api application.

That application, by default, has a Program.cs file. However, for some requirement of my application, I need to create a Startup class instead, implementing IStartup interface.

One of the methods I should implement in the Startup class is this: `public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`. That method returns an `IServiceProvider`. This is the implementation I already have:

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<SecuWebModulesAuthenticateContext>(options =>
        {
            options
                .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    #if DEBUG
            options.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
    #endif
        });

        // Agrega autenticación
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnUrl";
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["AuthJwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["AuthJwt:Audience"],
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    RequireExpirationTime = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["AuthJwt:Key"] ?? string.Empty))
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization();

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

With that, a warning is shown for the return statement, telling that I will create a new instance of the provider, instead of using the only instance in the system.

How can I do that then?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: .net 6 introduced new templates based on top level statements. You don't have to use them though, all the old patterns for build a `Startup` class still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the [generic hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) approach (the one supporting `Startup` classes) then you don't need to implement `IStartup` interface. If I understand correctly this interface was used quite long ago before ASP.NET Core 3 ([for example this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68047783/istartup-interface)). Nowadays [`Startup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0) classes rely purely on conventions and the `ConfigureServices` method should return `void`. Sample from the docs:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

**UPD**

The [`IStartup` interface used in article](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/asp-net-core/modular-monolith/) is a custom one, not the one from framework, so you can/need to declare your own one (I would suggest to use another name to avoid the confusion).

Comment: I am using IStartup implementation because I am programming a monolith modular application following these example: https://www.thinktecture.com/en/asp-net-core/modular-monolith/ but it is using .NET Core 5, so I am trying to translate that to .NET Core 7. To register modules, I need to implement IStartup, however, I am not succeeding yet. Maybe I should try another approach, for example, creating my own interface. Other fact is that I need to pass a Configuration object to retrieve appsettings.json values. By using IStartup interface I cannot pass it either.

Comment: @jstuardo var startup = new TStartup(); startup.ConfigureServices(services); ... - You don't need predefined IStartup interface for it (which is a wrong choice here). Create custom one like IModuleSetup with ConfigureServices returning void and use it

Comment: @jstuardo note that interface in article is a custom one and not the one from framework: _"This can be done by **defining** an `IStartup` interface"_. I would argue that it is a bit unfortunate naming.

Comment: @gutu-strong Thanks, I have created my own IStartup interface and followed the example in that page. Solution compiles and Swagger recognizes the route defined in the module but when testing, a 404 error is shown. Since this is other topic, I updated other question I had opened, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76196203/monolithic-modular-web-application-in-net-core-7. If you know how to solve that, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: @jstuardo was glad to help! Will try to look at the other question later (P.S. feel free to accept and upvote answer if it works for you;)